# Hide parts of tree with genealogytree

Tags: trees, genealogytree, genealogy

When dealing with a very large tree using `genealogytree`, I would like to isolate some parts; not just highlight, but isolate, meaning excluding everything else. The tree is already coded so I would prefer avoiding splitting it in two trees.

For example, below, is it possible to keep only the minimum leading from Grandpa Doe to Charles and siblings? So that:

[image]

becomes:

[image]

Preserved nodes could be indicated by family id or node id, for example. This can be cumbersome, but is much easier than commenting or deleting the extra lines of code. There might be a simple way of doing it, and that's what I am asking for here.

Another possibility, which would probably require a package enhancement, would be to detect who to keep in-between two nodes. From two node ids, it would join them with the shortest path, and add every missing parent (and, possibly siblings).

I have found the options `options for family` and `edges for family` but that is not a very sound approach to excludes nodes by setting a tiny size or a white color.

Code for first tree:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
%options for family={Smith}{box={width=2cm,colback=white}},
%edges for family={Smith}{none},
]
{
    parent[id=SmithDoe]{
        g[id=Arth2008,male]{Arthur\\\gtrsymBorn\,2008}
        c[id=Bert2010,female]{Berta\\\gtrsymBorn\,2010}
        c[id=Char2014,male]{Charles\\\gtrsymBorn\,2014}
        parent[id=Smith]{
            g[id=John1980,male]{John Smith\\\gtrsymBorn\,1980}
            p[id=GpSm1949,male]{Grandpa Smith\\\gtrsymBorn\,1949}
            p[id=GmSm1952,female]{Grandma Smith\\\gtrsymBorn\,1952}
        }
        parent[id=Doe]{
        g[id=Jane1982,female]{Jane Doe\\\gtrsymBorn\,1982}
        c[id=Harr1987,male]{Uncle Harry\\\gtrsymBorn\,1987}
        p[id=GpDo1955,male]{Grandpa Doe\\\gtrsymBorn\,1955}
        p[id=GmDo1956,female]{Grandma Doe\\\gtrsymBorn\,1956}
        }
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `ignore node` key, used as

```
ignore node={GpSm1949,GmSm1952,Harr1987}
```

I.e. it lets you provide a list of `id`s that you want to remove from the tree.

There are various options for ignoring stuff, see section 5.11 *Ignoring input* in the manual.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
  ignore node={GpSm1949,GmSm1952,Harr1987}
]
{
    parent[id=SmithDoe]{
        g[id=Arth2008,male]{Arthur\\\gtrsymBorn\,2008}
        c[id=Bert2010,female]{Berta\\\gtrsymBorn\,2010}
        c[id=Char2014,male]{Charles\\\gtrsymBorn\,2014}
        parent[id=Smith]{
            g[id=John1980,male]{John Smith\\\gtrsymBorn\,1980}
            p[id=GpSm1949,male]{Grandpa Smith\\\gtrsymBorn\,1949}
            p[id=GmSm1952,female]{Grandma Smith\\\gtrsymBorn\,1952}
        }
        parent[id=Doe]{
        g[id=Jane1982,female]{Jane Doe\\\gtrsymBorn\,1982}
        c[id=Harr1987,male]{Uncle Harry\\\gtrsymBorn\,1987}
        p[id=GpDo1955,male]{Grandpa Doe\\\gtrsymBorn\,1955}
        p[id=GmDo1956,female]{Grandma Doe\\\gtrsymBorn\,1956}
        }
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could it be adapted to ignore nodes _starting by_ `xyz`? That's to avoid enumerating all nodes in a long list.

Comment: @anderstood There is an `ignore subtree` key as well (manual section 5.11, as mentioned above), but `ignore subtree={Smith}` removes also John Smith. Beyond that,  I don't know more than what is said in the manual, which you can read as well as me.